# Date comparison in MongoDB Filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to create a Filter that will that will return the rows where at least one minute has passed from the stored transactionDate. I am not getting an error but it is not returning any rows. The transactionDate is a timestamp in MongoDB and is stored as "transactionDate" : ISODate("2016-09-30T20:29:19.448Z")

Thanks! \m/ \m/

```
var filter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Eq("Genre", "Rock");
filter = filter & (Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Lt(x => x.transactionDate, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Math.Abs(60) * (-1))));

using (var cursor = await MyCollection.Find(filter)
    .Sort(Builders<MyDocument>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.artist).Ascending(x => x.rating)).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        // foreach...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code actually does work. I had an issue in the data causing no results to be returned. \m/ \m/